# how to do a quick pilot run when pre-training a large language model?

Tags: chatgpt, llm, llama-2

As I know, it will take several months to pre-train an LLM like chatGPT. I am wondering, what is the industry standard practice to do a pilot run to make sure that everything is correct (as it will be too costly to figure out that something is wrong after finish training the entire model) for an LLM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to do a quick pilot run when pre-training a large language model?

1. Train a much smaller LLM (e.g., 100M or 1B parameters).
2. Monitor the evolution of the losses as the model is training.

Comment: that makes sense! Thank you!